# How should I reseal my cobblestone patio?

Tags: patio, pavers

*Disclaimer: I’m not a native speaker and, as such, I have limited vocabulary, especially in the home improvement department. I also have limited competence, but that’s another matter entirely.*

I’m currently cleaning my cobblestone patio — with an high-pressure washer and, no, they’re not set on a sand bed  — and I need to seal them again. What should I use to do so? Would sand suffice?

Comment: What do you mean by "seal?"  Are you talking about the material used to fill gaps between stones, or some coating on the stones themselves?

Comment: Material to fill the gap.

Answer (score 1):

They should be laid in a sand bad, but also you should bind them together with cement based mortar if they are not regular shaped. If they are all same shape you can stack them without mortar, but it is not simple. Maybe you should think about hiring experienced mason.

Comment: Not worth it for a place I rent. I’ll check with the architect that designed the place, I might be wrong about the bed, but it seems to me the stones were set directly on good old earth.

Comment: If you are renting it's not worth doing anything :) It is possible that it was set on ground without sand. It is not proper way, but also it is not the worst thing in the world. Not sure if architect could answer you, because it could be according to design but not how contractor did it. And since you are renting what kind of answer were you hoping for?

Comment: Quite frankly, something between “drop a bag of sand and brush it between the stones” and “drop a bag of joint sand, brush it between the stones and wet it slightly to set it”. Both of which should be south of 50€ and one afternoon of work.

Comment: Well, my solution isn't much more expensive or complex, but I guess you can just pour in fine sand; it would be the best if you pour it several times. Like you pour some today, than wait for it to settle maybe spray with some water, then add some more tomorrow. This solution is also ok, but you cannot wash it with pressured water etc.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood (I probably did), your solution also implies unsetting every stone. Because there’s no way I’ll bind some with cement without taking them off. Most are quite close.

Comment: Well if you want it done properly yes, that is the way, but it is not as hard as it might sound, trust mean takes less time than you would imagine. But like I said you can also just "grout „it with the fine sand it wouldn't be perfect but since you are renting...